# how to set default response on every request and handle 404 in ExpressJS wisely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just tried to learn Express, and I want to create default response object like this:

```js
{
  "success": true/false,
  "status": 200,
  "message": String // based on every routes message
  "data": Object||Array // based on every routes result
}
```

I've tried to googling using any keyword I know, unfortunately I'm not found it yet, so I create my own *way* something like this

`ResultHandler.js`

```js
exports.ErrorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const errStatus = err?.cause?.statusCode || 500;
  const errMsg = err.message || 'Something went wrong';
  res.status(errStatus).json({
    success: false,
    status: errStatus,
    message: errMsg,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? err.stack : {},
  });
};

exports.ResponseHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  const {data, status, message} = res.locals;
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    status: status || res.statusCode,
    message,
    data,
  });
};
```

`app.js`

```js
// other route and import
app.use('/api/', authRoute);
app.use('/api/', userRoute);

// put it on last `app.use`
app.use(ResponseHandler);
app.use(ErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

using this method, I can handle error/success response on every route like:

```js
// success response
res.locals.message = 'User found';
res.locals.data = userDetail;
next()

// error response
throw new Error('User not found', {
  cause: {statusCode: 400},
});
```

### Problem

I got a problem about how to manage non-exist route url using above method, since `ResponseHandler` always sending `res.status(200).json()`, so when client requesting `/non-exist-route`, express will return

```
{
  "success": true,
  "status": 200
}
```

### Question

1. So is there anyway to handle such a case? or is there any better way to create global response handler to create consistency response object and non-existing route a.k.a `404 Not Found`?
2. how to create only one `app.use('/api/')` with multiple routes? as you can see, currently I'm declaring every route in `app.js` like this

```js
app.use('/api/', authRoute);
app.use('/api/', userRoute);
```

Comment: You can use a middleWare